# How to add static library instead of a framework for Cordova ios plugin?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am building a plugin that wraps an SDK provided by some higher power.

And I wrote something like this:

```
<framework src="path/to/static-lib.a" custom="true" />
```

Cordova setup the `Framework Search Paths` in XCode Build Settings which is cool, but it seems that what I need is `Library Search Paths`.

How should I write the plugin.xml to add such a static library?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try with

```
<source-file src="srcpath/to/static-lib.a" framework="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hmm I should have searched the specification more carefully. T-T